# Pure Ruby AOP (for collecting analytics about user interactions)

Tags: ruby, aop, pointcut

Hi my application is already way too complicated to add some analytics code in it.

I really want to design special classes that will allow me to insert some AOP pointcuts (that will trigger some mixpanel).

I do not want to use a gem, only pure ruby. With modules, concerns, metaprogramming and whatnot.

Using just the callback before, around, after is not enough I would like to cut in a conditional for instance.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "no gem"? You want someone to give you a full analytics solution from scratch? In here?

Comment: no. forget about the analytic part. I just want to have special classes that insert code in my application at some specific points.

Comment: An obvious approach is to use `alias_method` to hide the original method that is being instrumented and replace with dynamically generated instrumenting wrapper. Although it is only marginally cleaner than using plain `around_action`.

Comment: Ok your solution is good. But imagine that my controller render  html and json (it is just 1 method). Is it possible to say "run some code before render html" "run some other code before render json" From the outside

Comment: @pierolele: everything is possible, given enough effort. :)